# Install different Silverlight application to desktop than the one that is running currently

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, xap

Specifically, I have the main application running in the browser.  I would like to offer a link to install a set of tools that provide the user to perform a subset of the functionality provided in the main application.  I'd like to have a link that says, "Install Tools," and this would in turn kick off the Out Of Browser installation of the tools, not the main application.

Answer (score 0):

So basically to solve this, I created a separate Silverlight application and provided a link to it from the original application.  It operates on the same data and the link makes it appear as if it were part of the main application.  In the new application I provide a link to "Install Tools" on their desktop.  It looks seemless and is a smaller footprint anyways.  Works for me!